# fix a committed mistake in subversion

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

This seems like one of the most basic things that one might want to do with subversion, but I haven't been using version control systems for very long and somehow I can't seem to figure this out and I have no idea where in the svn documentation to look.  Basically, revision 167 worked perfectly, but I made a mistake and committed it as revision 168 (and I'm not sure exactly where the mistake is).  I ran `svn update -r 167` and then `svn revert` to get my working copy back to revision 167, and everything works again.  Now, I want to just start over from here - i.e. make a small change to this working copy and commit it as revision 169, completely ignoring everything that I did on revision 168.

How do I do this?  When i try to just commit, tortoise svn gives me an error saying I need to update my working copy before I can commit, and obviously this is not what I want as it will bring me back to revision 168.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
svn merge -r 168:167
svn ci -m "removing changes from r168"
```

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo - here you can read about this technique in details.

as *David Rodríguez - dribeas* mentioned you should start with the `HEAD` revision. So perform `svn up` before the commands I adviced.

Comment: +1, note you have to start with `svn up -r168`, that is with the latest version, not with the last working version.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! (although you might want to update the answer slightly, I realized that you have to include a source at the end of the merge command, I just used my working copy after updating to head).  I had assumed that doing a merge would combine all of the non-conflicting differences between 167 and 168, which might not have fixed the problem, but it did not.  Now I know.

Answer (score 4):

In Subversion you cannot actually remove something you already committed. My advice is that you update your working copy to the latest revision and then open the "SVN Show Log" dialogue. Once in it, click on the mistaken revision and select the "Revert changes from this revision" context menu. Despite the name, it's not a `revert` operation (in Subversion revert means *remove uncommitted local changes*). TortoiseSVN will undo the changes in your local copy with a reverse merge operation. Check everything's fine and then commit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm sure this would have worked too but I used the command line solution, as I wanted to better understand the underlying svn commands.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using tortoise you can use see how to revert your commit [here](http://markphip.blogspot.com/2007/01/how-to-undo-commit-in-subversion.html). Otherwise zerkms's command line commands should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the TortoiseSVN documentation section titled [Roll back (Undo) revisions in the repository](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html). You can also access this documentation with the "Help" item in the TortoiseSVN context menu.