# How to revert a file to previous version using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How does one revert a file to its previous version using TortoiseSVN GUI?

Comment: There are multiple interpretations of "revert to a previous version", at least three answers below answer three different cases.  What do you mean?  Do you want to set your working copy back to an older revision than the current version, or do you want to undo changes that you have already committed, or changes you have *not* committed?  Or do you want something else altogether?

Comment: I want to undo the changes that I have committed into SVN

Comment: @user550265: If all you want is `undo` - look also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603536/fix-a-committed-mistake-in-subversion

Answer (score 29):

1. Click right mouse button on the needed file
2. Choose `Tostoise SVN` -> `Show log`
3. In the top part select needed revision
4. In the bottom part click on that file and select `Revert changes from this revision`

See [**TortoiseSVN Manual | Undoing changes**](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-guide.html#tsvn-qs-revert).

Comment: This will revert the changes that this revision did by reverse-merging them. This will not modify the current version to have the state of this revision, at least according to the messages in the TSVN gui.

Comment: @Fletch: the question was about **previous** version. It's true for the previous version, since reverse diff will produce the original state.

Comment: @zerkms Ahh true, you are technically right. The title "revert a file to previous version SVN tortoise" is confusing because it drops the article "a" or "its" which is crucial in making the distinction. Although this appears in the actual question but I didn't read that properly :-). To be honest I think he's just looking for the simple "revert" answer. But anyway, I'll stick in another answer to cover all cases.

Answer (score 7):

Revert will just remove all the current changes that you have, and put your code back to what ever version you are currently at. If you want to be at a different version, you have to go to tortoiseSVN -> Update to Revision.. and pick the revision.

Answer (score 3):

right click on file, go to tortoiseSVN submenu, click revert

Comment: Actually this will revert to the current revision. This command will just remove all local changes, that have not been committed yet.

Comment: Depends what you meant by previous - but zerkms's answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

The question is really a bit vague. But anyway, if you want to revert a file to any previous version:

1. Click right mouse button on the needed file
2. Choose `Tostoise SVN` -> `Show log`
3. In the top part select needed revision
4. In the bottom part click on that file and select `Save revision to...` and save it somewhere unrelated, on your desktop or whatever.
5. (You can close all the Tortoise dialog boxes.)
6. Copy the contents of the file you just saved over the one you want to revert.

Answer (score 0):

I see no mentions of TortoiseSVN Manual where you can get the answer. :(

See [**TortoiseSVN Manual | Undoing changes**](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-guide.html#tsvn-qs-revert).